# Parsing dissimilar type json response

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have a json response like so…

```
{
    "message_code": 1,
    "orderCount": 52,
    "productCount": 5,
    "outstandingPayment": [],

 "pendingOrder": [
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "grand_total": 67.85
             "customer_name": “xcvv”
            "mobile_number": 2147483647
        },
    ],
    "bestWishes": [
        {
            "customer_id": 1,
            "birth_date": "2018-02-02",
            "type": "birth_date",
            "customer_name": “xcvv”,
            "mobile_number": 2147483647
        },
        {
            "customer_id": 1,
            "anniversary_date": "2018-02-02",
            "type": "anniversary_date",
            "customer_name": “sdfs”,
            "mobile_number": 2147483647
        }
    ]
}
```

To parse `pendingOrder` I have made a struct like so:

```
struct PendingOrder: Codable {
    let order_id: Int
    let grand_total: Double
    let customer_name: String
    let mobileNo: Int

    init(order_id : Int, grand_total: Double, customer_name: String, mobileNo: Int) {
        self.order_id = order_id
        self.grand_total = grand_total
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.mobileNo = mobileNo
    }
}
```

But how can I make a struct for `bestWishes` since each dictionary has dissimilar data i.e.the 1st dictionary has a field `birth_date` &  the 2nd dictionary has a field `anniversary_date`...?

**EDIT:** While making Alamofire request, this is how I'm parsing each data and assigning them to struct..

```
  if let bestWishes = result["bestWishes"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    for anItem in bestWishes {
      guard let customerId = anItem["customer_id"] as? Int,
            let birthdate = anItem["birth_date"] as? String,
            let customerName = anItem["customer_name"] as? String,
            let mobNo = anItem["mobile_number"] as? Int,
            let anniversaryDate = anItem["anniversary_date"] as? String,
            let type = anItem["type"] as? String
                 else {continue}

           let bestWishes = BestWishes(customer_id: customerId, birthDate: birthdate, type: type, customer_name: customerName, mobileNo: mobNo, anniversaryDate: anniversaryDate)

           self.bestWishesArr.append(bestWishes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all when using `Codable` basically you don't need an initializer.

Without a custom initializer (related to `Codable`) the most suitable solution is to declare both dates as optional

```
struct BestWish: Codable {

        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case customerID = "customer_id"
            case birthDate = "birth_date"
            case anniversaryDate = "anniversary_date"
            case type
            case customerName = "customer_name"
            case mobileNumber = "mobile_number"
        }
    let customerID: Int
    let birthDate: String?
    let anniversaryDate: String?
    let type: String
    let customerName : String
    let mobileNumber: Int
}
```

With a custom initializer declare **one** property `date` and decode `anniversary` or `birth` depending on `type`

```
struct BestWish: Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case customerID = "customer_id"
        case birthDate = "birth_date"
        case anniversaryDate = "anniversary_date"
        case type
        case customerName = "customer_name"
        case mobileNumber = "mobile_number"
    }
    let customerID: Int
    let date: Date
    let type: String
    let customerName : String
    let mobileNumber: Int

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        customerID = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .customerID)
        type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        if type == "anniversary_date" {
            date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .anniversaryDate)
        } else {
            date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .birthDate)
        }
        customerName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .customerName)
        mobileNo = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .mobileNumber)
    }
}
```

You can distinguish the dates by the given `type` property.

---

To decode also the root object you need an umbrella struct

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    // let pendingOrder : [PendingOrder]
    let bestWishes : [BestWish]
}
```

Rather than the deserialized dictionary you have to get the JSON string in `Data` format from the Alamofire request to pass it to `JSONDecoder`

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

**Edit**: I added code to decode both dates as `Date`

Comment: Thanks @vadian. I'll just try..!

Comment: @vadian..I just edited the question and added how I was initially parsing each data and assigning them to struct. But with dissimilar types of data, of course it didn't work But how can I use your answer to achieve the same parsing, I'm confused...

Comment: what could be `data` in `Root.self, from: data`...?

Comment: That's supposed to be the Alamofire result, but the JSON string in `Data` format,  not the dictionary. I don't use Alamofire at all but there must be an option to get the raw data.

Comment: Ok @vadian. But is it the entire json response or just the part of response which has `bestWishes`..?

Comment: The entire response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162975/discussion-between-v-bw-and-vadian).

Answer (score 0):

Use optional type

```
struct BestWishes: Codable {
    let birth_date: Date?
    let anniversary_date: Date?

    init(birth_date : Date?, anniversary_date: Date?) {
        self.birth_date = birth_date
        self.anniversary_date = anniversary_date
    }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't seem to work @Алексей Кудлай..while parsing the response using for loop, the first time when it reaches `anniversaryDate` it shows `Unable to read data`